# Basic Console Calculator (Storing a string in a variable) C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a basic console calculator in C++. I'm having a bit of trouble storing a string in a variable from a `cin` command.

Here is the program for some clarification:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string type_cal;

    cout << "Please enter the type of calculation you would like to use: \n";
    cout << "1. Addition \n";
    cout << "2. Subtraction \n";
    cout << "3. Multiplication \n";
    cout << "4. Division \n \n";

    cin >> type_cal;

    if (type_cal = "Addition" or "1")
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int sum;

        cout << "Please enter a number to add: \n";
        cin >> a;

        cout << "Please enter another number: \n";
        cin >> b;

        sum = a + b;

        cout << "The sum of those numbers is: " << sum << endl;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Currently I am in the addition phase since I recently ran into this problem. Quick answers would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: For starters, my compiler gives me [one useful warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0084edc5fb537aa7).

Comment: One problem is that `=` is not `==`.  A compiler warning should catch this, but a good habit is always to put the constant in any comparison on the **left**, so that if you type `=` by mistake, it will always fail to compile.  That is, `"1" == type_cal` could not have compiled if you had made the same mistake.

Comment: It looks like you successfully read a string from `cin` and put it in `type_cal`. What makes you think it didn't get read properly?

Comment: Thanks Lorehead, that was a problem I didn't see. Also aerkenemesis helped me with the or command for c++. Everything works fine now!

Comment: You forgot to tell anyone what the problem is.

Comment: Please scroll down and read the comment by me

Answer (score 1):

if(type_cal = "Addition" or "1") simply does not make sense.

```
if(type_cal == "Addition" || type_cal == "1") {
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I forgot how to use the or operator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, or is actually used as || in c++ (thanks aerkenemesis), and = is not the same as == which means equal to (another thanks to Lorehed). Program is working fine now.

Comment: That is not the only problem. `x == y || z` is wrong (and usually stems from a common error in English, of all things); you need `x == y || x == z`.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure out that issue for a day now!

Comment: Not sure why, since everyone in the comments told you it at the time, not to mention the other answer (which you commented on at the time).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are curious, here is the new and revised version of my simple calculator:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float addition();
float subtraction();
float multiplication();
float division();

int main()
{
    string type_cal;

    cout << "Please enter the type of calculation you would like to use: \n";
    cout << "1. Addition " << endl;
    cout << "2. Subtraction " << endl;
    cout << "3. Multiplication " << endl;
    cout << "4. Division" << endl << endl;

    cin >> type_cal;

    if(type_cal == "Addition")
    {
        addition();
    }

    if(type_cal == "Subtraction")
    {
        subtraction();
    }

    if(type_cal == "Multiplication")
    {
        multiplication();
    }

    if(type_cal == "Division")
    {
        division();
    }

    return 0;
}



float addition()
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float sum;

    cout << "Please enter a number to add: " << endl;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Please enter another number: " << endl;;
    cin >> b;

    sum = a + b;

    cout << "The sum of those numbers is: " << sum << endl;
}




float subtraction()
{
    float c;
    float d;
    float difference;

    cout << "Please enter a number to subtract: \n";
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Please enter another number: \n";
    cin >> d;

    difference = c - d;

    cout << "The difference of those numbers is " << difference << endl;
}




float multiplication()
{
    float e;
    float f;
    float product;

    cout << "Please enter a number to multiply: \n";
    cin >> e;

    cout << "Please enter another number: \n";
    cin >> f;

    product = e * f;

    cout << "The product of those numbers is " << product << endl;
}




float division()
{
    float g;
    float h;
    float quotient;

    cout << "Please enter a number to divide: \n";
    cin >> g;

    cout << "Please enter another number: \n";
    cin >> h;

    quotient = g / h;

    cout << "The quotient of those numbers is " << quotient << endl;
}
```